# Not able to load module in Kernel it is showing Operation not permitted

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module

I have just started learning Kernel Module and I am on my first program, here is my code and Makefile

-->hello-1.c /**My first program**/

```
  #include <linux/module.h>
  #include <linux/kernel.h>
    int init_module(void ){
      printk(KERN_INFO "Hello this is known as module.\n" );
      return 0;
      }

  void cleanup_module(void ){
     printk(KERN_INFO "Bye. We'll come back soon.\n" );
   }
```

-->Makefile

```
obj-m += hello-1.o
  all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
  clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Now the issue is I am able to do `make all` but I am not able to load it,actually, I tried

`insmod ./hello-1.ko` It did not work for me.

--Error : insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./hello-1.ko: Operation not permitted

so, I did `sudo modprobe -v hello-1.ko`.

--Error : insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./hello-1.ko: Operation not permitted

But, while doing `lsmod` I am able to see my module and I am also able to do `modinfo hello_1`.

hence, I tried , `modprobe hello_1` but it is showing

--Error: modprobe: FATAL: Module hello_1 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-43-lowlatency

Please help me with where I am lacking as this is my first program. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you have already previously loaded the module. Have you tried `sudo rmmod hello_1` first and then `sudo modprobe` after that?

Comment: I have restarted my computer and tried the same what you just asked to do , but getting same error message. and Now I am not able to see my module while doing `lsmod`.

Comment: What does `dmesg` say after failed `insmod` call?